# How to Subclassing with Concrete Parameters

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-errors, subclassing, concreteclass

I have a class Transaction and a Service interface

```
public class Transaction {}

public interface RequestService {
    public String getRequest(Transaction transaction);
}
```

Now I want to subclass the Transaction class and have a concrete class for the Service Interface

```
public class ESPTransaction extends Transaction {}

public class ESPRequestService implements RequestService {
    @Override
    public String getRequest(ESPTransaction espTransaction) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(espTransaction.someMethodThatDoesntExistInParentClass());
        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

The IDE complains that, even though ESPTransaction subclasses Transaction, that I am not overriding the supertype method.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the IDE notes, `ESPRequestService` isn't properly implementing `RequestService`, since it doesn't have a `getRequest(Transaction)` method.

One neat solution is to make the interface generic, so each `RequestService` implementation can specify the type of `Transaction` it expects:

```
public interface RequestService<T extends Transaction> {
    public String getRequest(T transaction);
}

public class ESPRequestService implements RequestService<ESPTransaction> {
    @Override
    public String getRequest(ESPTransaction espTransaction) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(espTransaction.someMethodThatDoesntExistInParentClass());
        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```